# Xml well formed error while parsing the xml message

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-validation

Can anyone suggest me this error i am getting followin error in my console when i am parsing in java using documentbuilderfactory **"The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message name="LANE_SELECTED" sentDateTime="2005-10-17T08:26:00.0000000-07:00">
<submitToTos>
    <!-- InGate 01 -->
    <pedestalName>IG01</pedestalName>
    <!-- smartGate Visit Number -->
    <transactionID>124</transactionID>
    <!-- Driver details, if obtained from the card -->
    <driverID>DL23434</driverID>
    <gatePass>2323</gatePass>
    <grossWeight>40230</grossWeight>
    <consoleID>C01</consoleID>
    <!-- Container captured through OCR -->
    <container>NYKU6052654</container>
    <!-- Chassis captured through OCR -->
    <chassis>APMZ234323</chassis>
  </submitToTos>
</message>
```

Comment: That markup is well formed.

Comment: Make sure there aren't hidden non-ascii characters somewhere in your real document.